# Create Custom control with Event click

Tags: android, android-layout, custom-controls

I am creating a custom control as below in the image. It is a semicircle with places 1, 2 etc. 
[image: image1]

When user click on one place (1, 2 etc), it changes color (for example user click on place 3, image 2).

[image: image2]

I try to use `canvas` and methods draws. But I don't think that is correct. Can you help me with a better solution and how to set up an event for user clicking on the place?

Comment: i also think that i can use shape in drawable, what are you think? is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with the `canvas`, bellow is a small example of a `View` with 2 oval shapes that change color(to red) on a touch event:

```
class ExtraView extends View {

        private boolean flag1, flag2;
        private Paint p1, p2;
        private RectF oval1, oval2;

        public ExtraView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            flag1 = false;
            flag2 = false;
            // bigger oval paint
            oval1 = new RectF(50, 50, 460, 360);
            p1 = new Paint();
            p1.setStrokeWidth(2.0f);
            // smaller oval paint
            oval2 = new RectF(140, 140, 360, 260);
            p2 = new Paint();
            p2.setStrokeWidth(2.0f);
        }

        @Override
        public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawColor(Color.GREEN);
            // bigger oval
            if (flag1) {
                p1.setColor(Color.RED);
            } else {
                p1.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
            p1.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            canvas.drawOval(oval1, p1);
            p1.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            p1.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            canvas.drawOval(oval1, p1);
            // smaller oval
            if (flag2) {
                p2.setColor(Color.RED);
            } else {
                p2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
            p2.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            canvas.drawOval(oval2, p2);
            p2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            p2.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            canvas.drawOval(oval2, p2);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (oval2.contains(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
                    flag2 = !flag2;
                    invalidate();
                } else if (oval1.contains(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
                    flag1 = !flag1;
                    invalidate();
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```